# Moment JS Неправильная конвертация даты в число

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Пробую преобразовать дату 05/06/2019 (DD/MM/YYYY) в число (UNIX формат)

```
var now = moment('05/06/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
alert(now.format('X'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsabnuec/

Получается 1559682000, но это число соответствует другой дате! Должно было получиться 1559718000. Почему ?

Comment: Кому должно? Вангую,  что дело в часовом поясе

Comment: `1559682000 - Wed Jun 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0300`

`1559718000 - Wed Jun 05 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix timestamp всегда с нулевым сдвигом (часового пояса) - поэтому, форматируемое значение даты должно быть по UTC:

```js
var now = moment.utc('05/06/2019', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log('result: ' + now.format('X'));

console.log('test: ' + new Date(now).toUTCString());
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/moment"></script>
```

*p.s.: Вместо `.format('X')` можно использовать метод `.unix()`, который выглядит гораздо понятнее.*